# Windows ImportError numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: windows, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, setup.py

I write the application using modules PyQt4, cv2(v.2.4.13), numpy(v.1.11.1) and etc. I use Python (2.7.11 on win32), Windows7 (x64).

Before the compiling (using py2exe) on Windows my application work correctly (run from python).

In setup.py:

```
...
options = {
        'py2exe': {
        ...
        'compressed': True,
        'includes': ['cv2', 'numpy', 'sip', 'lxml._elementpath', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.QtGui' ],
        'dll_excludes': ['MSVCP90.dll', 'w9xpopen.exe', 'Qwt.pyd', 'tcl85.dll', 'tk85.dll']
        }
}
...
```

After compiling on Windows and trying to start the apps (*.exe file) the system return this error:

> File "cv2.pyc", line 12, in module
>
> File "cv2.pyc", line 10, in __load
>
> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import.

The exception raised in line:

```
import cv2
```

In the folder named 'dist' there is file numpy.core.multiarray.pyd.
In library.zip there are file cv2, folder numpy.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

The problem was in setup.py in the py2exe section.

Also I copied numpy-atlas.dll from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core to site-packages for succesful build.

setup.py:

```
excludes = [
    'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter', 'tcl', '_ssl',  'bz2',
    '_testcapi', 'pyexpat', 'select'
]
options = {
    'py2exe': {
        'compressed': True,
        'excludes': excludes,
        'includes': ['sip', 'lxml._elementpath', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.QtGui', 'cv2', 'numpy'],
        'dll_excludes': ['MSVCP90.dll', 'w9xpopen.exe', 'Qwt.pyd', 'tcl85.dll', 'tk85.dll', 'MSVCR90.DLL']
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for me the solution was as easy as moving the image file to the folder where the executable was created. This worked for both py2exe and pyinstaller.